# Want to show date in GMT format like 11-Aug-11 18:20 GMT in PHP?

Tags: php, date-formatting

I want to show a date in GMT format like `11-Aug-11 18:20 GMT` in PHP.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = epoch time from previous date. time();

echo gmdate('d-M-y H:i').' GMT';
echo gmdate('d-M-y H:i',$timestamp).' GMT';
```

gmdate() is the same as date() but GMT time.

Answer (score 0):

php site can help you try to visit this this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: my dear we comes on forum to save time not to read long articals. :), bTw thanks for the reply, i got my answer as in above post